# ArcGIS Error 000732

Tags: python, arcgis

I am running a query to select a polygon from a set of polygons. Then I input that polygon into a feature dataset in a geodatabase. I then use this polygon(or set of polygons) to dissolve to get the boundary of the polygons and the centroid of the polygon(s), also entered into separate feature datasets in a geodatabase.

```
import arcpy, os

#Specify the drive you have stored the NCT_GIS foler on
drive = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = (drive + ":\\NCT_GIS\\DATA\\RF_Properties.gdb")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


lot_DP = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1).split(';')
PropertyName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
queryList= []

for i in range(0,len(lot_DP)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        lt = lot_DP[i]
        DP = lot_DP[i+1]
        query_line = """( "LOTNUMBER" = '{0}' AND "PLANNUMBER" = {1} )""".format(lt, DP)
        queryList.append(query_line)
        if i < (len(lot_DP)):
           queryList.append(" OR ")
del queryList[len(queryList)-1]        
query = ''.join(queryList)
#Feature dataset for lot file
RF_Prop = drive + ":\\NCT_GIS\\DATA\\RF_Properties.gdb\\Lots\\"
#Feature dataset for the property boundary
RF_Bound = drive + ":\\NCT_GIS\\DATA\\RF_Properties.gdb\\Boundary\\"
#Feature dataset for the property centroid
RF_Centroid = drive + ":\\NCT_GIS\\DATA\\RF_Properties.gdb\\Centroid\\"

lotFile = drive + ":\\NCT_GIS\\DATA\\NSWData.gdb\\Admin\\cadastre"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lotFile, "lot_lyr") 
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lot_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", query)
#Create lot polygons in feature dataset
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lot_lyr", RF_Prop + PropertyName)
#Create property boundary in feature dataset
arcpy.
arcpy.Dissolve_management(RF_Prop + PropertyName , RF_Bound + PropertyName, "", "", "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
#Create property centroid in feature dataset
arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(RF_Bound + PropertyName, RF_Centroid + PropertyName, "CENTROID")
```

Every time I run this I get an error when trying to add anything to the `geodatabase` EXCEPT when copying the lot layer into the geodatabase. 
I have tried not copying the lots into the geodatabase and copying it into a shapefile and then using that but still it the boundary and centroid will not import into the geodatabase. I tried outputing the boundaries into shapefiles then using the FeatureClassToGeodatabase tool but still I get error after error.

If anyone can shed light on this It would be grateful

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I found out that if I had recently opened then closed ArcMap or ArcCatalog it would leave two ArcGIS services running (check task manager) even though I had closed ArcMap and ArcCatalog.  If I tried running a script while these two services were running I would get this error.  Finding these services in Windows task manager and ending them fixed this error for me.  The two services were

1. ArcGIS cache manager
2. ArcGIS online services

I've also heard that your computer's security/anti-virus software may possibly interfere with scripts running. So adding your working directory as an exception to your security software may also help.

If in the rare occasions that this didn't work I just had to restart the computer.